# How to set decimal mask in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to set a decimal mask with two digits to my javascript application. I tried to use the following solution since I am using ui-mask across all the masks that I have at the moment:

```
<input id="DebitValue" type="text" placeholder="{{appResources.ContractCreateEditPaymentValuePlaceholder}}" ng-model="DebitValue" ui-mask-placeholder ui-mask="?9?9??9?9?9?9?.?9?9?" model-view-value="true" name="DebitValue" required>
```

But I am failing to achieve what I want, since I can not for instance insert `0.99` as value, I would need to insert `000000.99`.

I checked this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269742/input-mask-for-numeric-and-decimal) also, but neither the `numeric` or `inputmask` did nothing to my input, I just was able to write whatever I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/"` to accept only numbers with a maximum of 2 decimal places and with a dot separator.

If you want something more, then use a directive like:

```
.directive('currencyInput', function ($browser, $filter) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel) {
            var listener = function () {
                var value = $element.val().replace(/,/g, '');
                $element.val($filter('number')(value, 0));
            };

            // This runs when we update the text field from element
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                return parseInt(viewValue.replace(/,/g, ''), 10);
            });

            // This runs when the model gets updated on the scope directly and keeps our view in sync
            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
                return modelValue == null || modelValue.length === 0 ? '' : $filter('number')(modelValue, 0);
            });

            ngModel.$viewChangeListeners = function () {
                $element.val($filter('number')(ngModel.$viewValue, 0))
            }

            $element.bind('change', listener);
            $element.bind('keypress', function (event) {
                var key = event.which;
                // If the keys include the CTRL, SHIFT, ALT, or META keys, or the arrow keys, do nothing.
                // This lets us support copy and paste too
                if (key === 0 || key === 8 || (15 < key && key < 19) || (37 <= key && key <= 40)) {
                    return;
                }
                $browser.defer(listener); // Have to do this or changes don't get picked up properly
            });
            $element.bind('paste cut', function () {
                $browser.defer(listener);
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Then use it on input elements, let's say:

```
<input currency-input ng-maxlength="10" ng-model="myDecimal" type="text">
```

If you want just two decimals, you should either hardcode number filter or receive it as parameter to directive:

```
$element.val($filter('number')(value, 2));
```

Comment: I already tried that solution, but that won't stop me from write what I want, it will just validate that it does not follow the pattern, am I right?

Comment: @RuiQueirós yes. I edited and added a directive that will help you to copy paste values or mask and have the desired result. I hope it helps you.

Comment: @RuiQueirós also you should mention in the title that you are looking for an AngularJS solution, not pure javascript.

Comment: it can be pure javascript, does not matter

Comment: will test your directive

Comment: I am trynig to use your solution, but nothing happens